# PUG: Can't pass object into script

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a problem, I can't pass my variable in my script tag in my pug file.

```
    - var toto = JSON.stringify({"lol":"azd", "lol2":"gdc"});
    script.
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var te = JSON.parse("#{toto}");
            console.log(te.lol);
        });
```

Result in html:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var te = "{&quot;lol&quot;:&quot;azd&quot;,&quot;lol2&quot;:&quot;gdc&quot;}";
        console.log(te.lol);
    });
```

Result in console:

```
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Thanks for your help !

Panorius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `toto`'s value is escaped. Use `!` to use unescaped value:

```
- var toto = JSON.stringify({"lol":"azd", "lol2":"gdc"});
script.
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var te = JSON.parse("!{toto}");
        console.log(te.lol);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks guy :)
Speed ;)